# Do all submodules of $R^n$ have a complement in $R^n$?

Tags: modules

Suppose that $M=R^n$,
    where $n\geq 1$ and $R$ is a PID and suppose $N\leq M$.
    A \emph{complement} of $N$ in $M$ is a submodule $P$ of $M$
    so that $M=N\oplus P$ (internal).
    If $A\in M_{n\times n}(R)$,
    the \emph{nullspace} of $A$ is the submodule $\{x\in M\mid Ax=0\}$.
    Show that
    $$N\text{ has a complement in }M\Leftrightarrow N\text{ is the null space of some }A\in M_{n\times n}(R).$$
    Do all submodules of $M$ have a complement in $M$?

From the RHS to the LHS, I know that $N$ is a free module. And I try to expand the basis of $N$ to the basis of $M$ but I don't know whether I can do this. From the LFS to the RHS, I think should I give out an $A$ whose solution space is generated by the basis of $N$?

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: No. For example, $2 \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a complement in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The null space of a matrix is not necessarily a free module.

Comment: @JulianRosen I'm a little confused about that. In this problem, $M=R^n$ which means $M$ is a free module. Since the null space is a submodule, we can see that the null space of $M$ is free as well.

Comment: @Boga: submodules of free modules don't need to be free.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think If the module is over a PID, then submodule of a free module is free.

Comment: @Boga: yes, that's correct, but I don't see that assumption in the problem statement.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I miss to add the condition!

Answer (score 1):

No. A direct sum decomposition of a ring $R=I\oplus J$ corresponds to a pair of orthogonal idempotents, which  do not exist except $0$ and $1$ in integral domains or local rings, for instance.

Furthermore, a submodule of a free module is not necessarily free, except in PIDs. It isn't even a projective module in general.

Comment: I see, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a counter example. Can you help me with the proof of the existence of complement is equivalent to its being a null space of some A?

Comment: I can't: it is false. The situation is *very* different from the situation in vector spaces, due to the lack of invertible elements in rings. A direct summand of a free module is a projective module, but is not a free module itself in general.